# Understand the compile time error with Method Reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

As per the Documentation, Method Reference is absolutely not a static call. It works on both static and non- static methods.
When we define our own non-static method in a given class and try to use it using Method Reference then the compile-time-error "cannot make static reference to non static method" is NOT seen in case of Function but only seen in case of Supplier, Consumer and Predicate. Why is that so?

```
class Demo{
    private Function<Student, Integer> p= Student::getGradeLevel; // fine
    private Supplier<Integer> s = Student::supply; // compile-time error
    private Predicate<Integer> p1= Student::check; //compile-time error
    private Consumer<Integer> c=  Student::consume; / compile-time error
    private Function<String, String> f1 = String::toUpperCase; //fine
}

class Student{
    public int getGradeLevel() {
        return gradeLevel;
    }

    public boolean check(int i) {
        return true;
    }

    public int supply() {
        return 1;
    }

    public void consume(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would rather suggest you visit the [official documentation about types of method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). The reason why the first line of code compiles is that it can represent the instance method of a `Student` type such as `student -> student.getGradeLevel`. This is easy to understand when related to using the `Function` since that is when you do `p.apply(<the arbitrary object>)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow both the return type and the formal parameter type of the `Student` method and use the appropriate functional interface.

---

> `private Supplier<Integer> s = Student::supply; // compile-time error`

The `Supplier<T>` consumes *nothing* and returns `T`. An example would be:

```
Student student = new Student();
Supplier<Integer> s = () -> student.supply();
```

The relevant functional interface for the method reference `Student::supply` is
`Function<T, R>`. The both following are equal:

```
Function<Student, Integer> function = student -> student.supply();
Function<Student, Integer> function = Student::supply;

// You have already used a method reference with the very same return and parameter types
Function<Student, Integer> p = Student::getGradeLevel;
```

---

> `private Predicate<Integer> p1 = Student::check; // compile-time error`

The very same issue but `Predicate<T>` *consumes* `T` and returns `Boolean`.

```
Student student = new Student();
Predicate<Integer> p =  i -> student.check(i);
```

You can use `BiPredicate<T, R>` that results in `Boolean` if you want to use `Student::check` method reference:

```
BiPredicate<Student, Integer> biPredicate = (student, integer) -> student.check(integer);
BiPredicate<Student, Integer> biPredicate = Student::check;
```

---

> `private Consumer<Integer> c =  Student::consume; // compile-time error`

Again nothing new, `Consumer<T>` consumes `T` and returns *nothing* (the return type is `void`).

```
Student student = new Student();
Consumer<Integer> c = integer -> student.consume(integer);
```

The method reference `Student::consume` is suitable for `BiConsumer` consuming both `Student` and some `Integer`:

```
BiConsumer<Student, Integer> biConsumer = (student, integer) -> student.consume(integer);
BiConsumer<Student, Integer> biConsumer = Student::consume;
```