# Method reference expression is not expected here, compile time error

Tags: java, list, lambda, hashmap, java-stream

I am using stream to iterate through the list and want to collect it in the map but getting compile time error:

> Method reference expression is not expected here

Here is my code

```
List<Person> personList = getPersons();
Map<String, Integer> personAgeMap = personList.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getFirstName + "_" + Person::getLastName, Person::getAge));
```

I have checked these answers:

- [Java Method reference not expected here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440548/java-method-reference-not-expected-here)
- [Understand the compile time error with Method Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842848/understand-the-compile-time-error-with-method-reference)

but these are not what i am looking for, also i have seen the method reference type.

In this case it is instance method of instance type, how can i have instance of Person in the collectors.

what could be the possible solution or is it even doable this way?

Comment: `Person::getFirstName + "_" + Person::getLastName` is invalid syntax I think, you can't concatenate method references to strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a method reference in there. Try a lambda instead.

```
Collectors.toMap(
    p -> String.format("%s_%s", p.getFirstName(), p.getLastName()), 
    Person::getAge
)
```

Both `Person::getFirstName` and `Person::getLastName` are instances of some functional interface (never of `String`), for example `Supplier<String>` or `Function<Person, String>`, and the operator `+` can't be applied to them.

Similarly, it wouldn't make much sense, if you were

```
Object o = new Object() + new Object();
```

To puzzle you a bit

```
p -> ((Function<Person, String>) Person::getFirstName).apply(p) + "_" + 
     ((Function<Person, String>) Person::getLastName).apply(p)
```

Comment: What you are saying is right, but I thought the way we are expecting age from Person::getAge statement same way I was expecting string output from Person::getFirstName and Person::getLastName and then was applying concatenation.
Now I understood.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, it makes no sense:

```
Collectors.toMap(Person::getFirstName + "_" + Person::getLastName
```

You need to understand what the signature of the **toMap** method is. To keep things simple, let's say that it's:

```
void toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper)
```

You see? **keyMapper** is an object of type Function. The function takes an input (a Person) and returns an output (a String). So you need to provide a function which does that. If you write

```
Person::getFirstName + "_" + Person::getLastName
```

then that is... well, nothing, but let's say in the worst case it could be a String. Because you're concatenating 3 things with a String. It's not a function. What you want is to create a function.

So you can do this:

```
Collectors.toMap(new Function<Person, String>() {
   public String apply(Person person) {
      return person.getFirstName() + "_" + person.getLastName();
   }
});
```

Shorthand for that is:

```
Collectors.toMap(person -> person.getFirstName() + "_" + person.getLastName()
```

Answer (score 1):

Method references are used to refere a method in a lambda. It doesn't call the method, it provides its references to the lambda.

Which means that you can't use method reference in the same way as you call the method, so `Person::getFirstName + "_" + Person::getLastName` isn't right.

So in order to get the result you want, you could just use basic lambda expression like that:

```java
List<Person> personList = getPersons();
Map<String, Integer> personAgeMap = personList.stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(person -> person.getFirstName() + "_" + person.getLastName(), Person::getAge));
```

Hope I got useful.